# Как в Django 3 прописать в urls чтобы модель отображалась на всех страницах?

Tags: django, django-urls

Делаю вывод категорий из модели Django 3.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что прописать в urls, чтобы список категорий показывался на всех страницах, а не на одной, как сейчас:

```
path('category', views.CategoryListView.as_view()),
```

Comment: а делать запрос на бэк с фронта не вариант?

Comment: опишите подробнее, что требуется. возможно вам нужен шаблонный тег

Comment: посмотри в сторону контекст процессоров

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, если я правильно понял суть вопроса, и Категории это отдельная модель, можно передавать Категории в контексте View например главной страницы

**views.py**

```
#...
from .models import Category #.....

class BaseView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        products = Product.objects.all()  # вместо *products* могут быть любые необходимые модели.
        context = {
                'categories': categories,
                'products': products,
            }
        return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

Далее в базовом template html выводим их где надо, например так:

**base(index).html**

```
{% for category in categories %}
   <a class="" href="{{ url ... }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

так как другие темплейты наследуются от базового с помощью `{% extends 'base.html' %}`
категории будут рендериться и на них.
Можно и отдельно в нужных View добавлять модель Категорий в контекст...